# MouseEvent Not Happening On Click AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

This looks all fine to me, but I have a simple star shape on the screen and when that star shape has been clicked it should remove the image from the screen. Can't see why its not working hoping one of you can, would be much appreciated

```
public class TouchRemove extends Sprite
{   
    private var _color:uint;
    private var _radius:int;
    private var star:Sprite;

    public function mouseClick(event:MouseEvent): void {
        star.visible = false;
    }

    public function TouchRemove(c:uint = 0xffff00, r:int = 100)
    {

        _color = c;
        _radius = r;

        star = new Sprite();

        createStar();
        addChild(star);
        star.x = 250;

        star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);

    }
    private function createStar():void
    {
        star.graphics.lineStyle(9,_color);
        star.graphics.moveTo(_radius, 0);

        var angleIncrement = Math.PI / 5;
        var ninety:Number = Math.PI * 3;

        for (var i:int = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
        {
            var radius:Number = (i % 2 > 0 ? _radius : _radius * .5);
            var px:Number = Math.cos(ninety + angleIncrement * i) * radius;
            var py:Number = Math.sin(ninety + angleIncrement * i) * radius;
            if (i == 0) star.graphics.moveTo(px, py);
            star.graphics.lineTo(px, py);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct.
Try this:
- Add listener to the parent
- Add star manually and add listener at it through the code
This will help locate the error.

Comment: moved into the TouchRemove method and now it works, weird but hay it works, cheers